# dependency-injection argument null exception

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection

I have a Startup.cs file with Dependency Injection as follows:

```
    public class Startup : FunctionsStartup
    {
        public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
        {                       
            builder.Services.Configure<RequestLocalizationOptions>(opts =>
            {
                var supportedCultures = new List<CultureInfo>
                        {
                            new CultureInfo("en-US"),
                            new CultureInfo("es-ES"),
                            new CultureInfo("hi-IN")
                        };
                opts.DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture("en-US");
                opts.SupportedCultures = supportedCultures;
                opts.SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures;
            });         
            builder.Services.AddSingleton<ILocalizationRepository, LocalizationRepository>();
        }
    }
```

I have the following Interface and Class 'LocalizationRepository':

```
    public interface ILocalizationRepository
    {
        string TranslateSetting(string settingName, params int[] additionalParams);
    }
    
    
    public class LocalizationRepository : ILocalizationRepository
    {
        private readonly IStringLocalizer<LocalizationRepository> _localizer;
        public LocalizationRepository(IStringLocalizer<LocalizationRepository> localizer)
        {
            _localizer = localizer ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(localizer));
        }

        public string TranslateSetting(string settingName, params int[] additionalParams)
        {
            return _localizer.GetString(settingName, additionalParams);
        }
    }
```

On running this, I see an ArgumentNullException - Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'localizer'). What am I missing?

Call Stack:

```
System.ArgumentNullException:
   at Repositories.Localization.LocalizationRepository..ctor (Repositories.Localization, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=nullRepositories.Localization, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null: D:\a\1\s\Service\Repositories.Localization\LocalizationRepository.csRepositories.Localization, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null: 12)
   at lambda_method (Anonymously Hosted DynamicMethods Assembly, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null)
   at DryIoc.Factory+<>c__DisplayClass26_0.<ApplyReuse>b__2 (Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.WebHost, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=nullMicrosoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.WebHost, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null: D:\a\1\s\src\WebJobs.Script.WebHost\DependencyInjection\DryIoc\Container.csMicrosoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.WebHost, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null: 6605)
   at DryIoc.Scope.TryGetOrAdd (Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.WebHost, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=nullMicrosoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.WebHost, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null: D:\a\1\s\src\WebJobs.Script.WebHost\DependencyInjection\DryIoc\Container.csMicrosoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.WebHost, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null: 7849)
   at DryIoc.Scope.GetOrAdd (Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.WebHost, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=nullMicrosoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.WebHost, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null: D:\a\1\s\src\WebJobs.Script.WebHost\DependencyInjection\DryIoc\Container.csMicrosoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.WebHost, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null: 7834)
   at DryIoc.Factory.ApplyReuse (Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.WebHost, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=nullMicrosoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.WebHost, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null: D:\a\1\s\src\WebJobs.Script.WebHost\DependencyInjection\DryIoc\Container.csMicrosoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.WebHost, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null: 6604)
   at DryIoc.Factory.GetExpressionOrDefault (Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.WebHost, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=nullMicrosoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.WebHost, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null: D:\a\1\s\src\WebJobs.Script.WebHost\DependencyInjection\DryIoc\Container.csMicrosoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.WebHost, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null: 6564)
   at DryIoc.ReflectionFactory.CreateExpressionOrDefault (Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.WebHost, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=nullMicrosoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.WebHost, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null: D:\a\1\s\src\WebJobs.Script.WebHost\DependencyInjection\DryIoc\Container.csMicrosoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.WebHost, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null: 7083)
   at DryIoc.Factory.GetExpressionOrDefault (Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.WebHost, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=nullMicrosoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.WebHost, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null: D:\a\1\s\src\WebJobs.Script.WebHost\DependencyInjection\DryIoc\Container.csMicrosoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.WebHost, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null: 6554)
   at DryIoc.ReflectionFactory.CreateExpressionOrDefault (Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.WebHost, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=nullMicrosoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.WebHost, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null: D:\a\1\s\src\WebJobs.Script.WebHost\DependencyInjection\DryIoc\Container.csMicrosoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.WebHost, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null: 7083)
   at DryIoc.Factory.GetExpressionOrDefault (Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.WebHost, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=nullMicrosoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.WebHost, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null: D:\a\1\s\src\WebJobs.Script.WebHost\DependencyInjection\DryIoc\Container.csMicrosoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.WebHost, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null: 6554)
   at DryIoc.Factory.GetDelegateOrDefault (Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.WebHost, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=nullMicrosoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.WebHost, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null: D:\a\1\s\src\WebJobs.Script.WebHost\DependencyInjection\DryIoc\Container.csMicrosoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.WebHost, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null: 6634)
   at DryIoc.Container.ResolveAndCacheDefaultFactoryDelegate (Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.WebHost, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=nullMicrosoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.WebHost, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null: D:\a\1\s\src\WebJobs.Script.WebHost\DependencyInjection\DryIoc\Container.csMicrosoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.WebHost, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null: 211)
   at DryIoc.Container.DryIoc.IResolver.Resolve (Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.WebHost, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=nullMicrosoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.WebHost, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null: D:\a\1\s\src\WebJobs.Script.WebHost\DependencyInjection\DryIoc\Container.csMicrosoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.WebHost, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null: 196)
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.WebHost.DependencyInjection.ScopedServiceProvider.GetService (Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.WebHost, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=nullMicrosoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.WebHost, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null: D:\a\1\s\src\WebJobs.Script.WebHost\DependencyInjection\ScopedServiceProvider.csMicrosoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.WebHost, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null: 25)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.GetService (Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions, Version=3.1.8.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
   at lambda_method (Anonymously Hosted DynamicMethods Assembly, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null)
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.DefaultJobActivator.CreateInstance (Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=3.0.23.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=3.0.23.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35: C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Executors\DefaultJobActivator.csMicrosoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=3.0.23.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35: 37)
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.DefaultJobActivator.CreateInstance (Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=3.0.23.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=3.0.23.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35: C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Executors\DefaultJobActivator.csMicrosoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=3.0.23.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35: 32)
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.ActivatorInstanceFactory`1+<>c__DisplayClass1_1.<.ctor>b__0 (Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=3.0.23.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=3.0.23.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35: C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Executors\ActivatorInstanceFactory.csMicrosoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=3.0.23.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35: 20)
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.ActivatorInstanceFactory`1.Create (Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=3.0.23.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=3.0.23.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35: C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Executors\ActivatorInstanceFactory.csMicrosoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=3.0.23.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35: 26)
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionInvoker`2.CreateInstance (Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=3.0.23.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=3.0.23.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35: C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Executors\FunctionInvoker.csMicrosoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=3.0.23.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35: 44)
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor+ParameterHelper.Initialize (Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=3.0.23.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=3.0.23.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35: C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Executors\FunctionExecutor.csMicrosoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=3.0.23.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35: 794)
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor+<TryExecuteAsyncCore>d__16.MoveNext (Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=3.0.23.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=3.0.23.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35: C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Executors\FunctionExecutor.csMicrosoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=3.0.23.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35: 96)
```

Comment: Are you adding in the ConfigureServices the AddLocalization?

Comment: " I see an ArgumentNullException." Please post the full stack trace of the exception and all its inner exceptions.